# Creating a translator in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a simple program in Matlab where the user can input a string (such as "A", "B", "AB" or "A B") and the program will output a word corresponding to my letter.

```
Input | Output
A        Hello
B        Hola
AB       HelloHola
A B      Hello Hola
```

This is my code:

```
A='Hello'; B='Hola';
userText = input('What is your message: ', 's');
userText = upper(userText);

    for ind = 1:length(userText)
        current = userText(ind);
        X = ['The output is ', current];
        disp(X);

    end
```

Currently I don't get my desired results. I instead get this:

```
Input | Output
A       The output is A
B       The output is B
```

I'm not totally sure why `X = ['The output is ', current];` evaluates to `The output is A` instead of `The output is Hello`.

---

### **Edit:**

How would this program be able to handle numbers... such as `1 = "Goodbye"`

Answer (score 4):

What's going on:

```
%// intput text
userText = input('What is your message: ', 's');

%// ...and some lines later
X = ['The output is ',  userText];
```

You never map what you *type* to what is contained by the variables `A` and `B`.

The fact that they are *called* `A` and `B` has *nothing* to do with what you type. You could call them `C` and `blargh` and still get the same result.

Now, you could use `eval`, but that's really not advisable here. In this case, using `eval` would force the one typing in the strings to know the exact names of your variables...that's a portability, maintainability, security, etc. disaster waiting to happen.

There are better solutions possible, for instance, create a simple map:

```
map = {
    'A'   'Hello'
    'B'   'Hola'
    '1'   'Goodbye'
};

userText = input('What is your message: ', 's');
str = map{strcmpi(map(:,1), userText), 2};

disp(['The output is ', str]);
```

Comment: This solution is great, especially since it does not use any loops. The only issue I foresee is if this needs to map to multiple values. Surely it could be tweaked to handle this.

Comment: @MZimmerman6: Of course, to do this properly, many more things need to be added/tweaked; the user might type something that is not in the map, `'a'` and `'A'` should actually map to different values, etc., to name a few examples.

Comment: Note: This will also fail if the user enters characters that are not defined already.

Comment: very true, to make something like this truly robust, much much more would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a map object to contain what you want. This will circumvent the `eval` function (which I suggest avoiding like the plague). This is pretty simple to read and understand, and is pretty efficient especially in the case of a long input string.

```
translation = containers.Map()
translation('A') = 'Hola';
translation('B') = 'Hello';
translation('1') = 'Goodbye';

inputString = 'ABA1BA1B11ABBA';

resultString = '';
for i = 1:length(inputString)
    if translation.isKey(inputString(i))
        % get mapped string if it exists
        resultString = [resultString,translation(inputString(i))];
    else
        % if mapping does not exist, simply put the input string in (covers space case)
        resultString = [resultString,inputString(i)];
    end
end
```

Comment: To achieve this, you could simply add cast the number to a string/character using `num2str(1)` or something like that. However, this should not be an issue because the input method you are using is automatically saying that whatever the user inputs, is to be interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the command `eval`. Currently, you are displaying the name of the variable that contains the string you want. `eval` will help you in actually accessing and printing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do it :

```
X = ['The output is ', eval(current)];
```

Here the documentation : [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)

Comment: And I think you need to add special handle for space `' '`.

Comment: Since he eval every char one by on in a loop, it okay. But To eval the full string is different.

Comment: A "map" is definitely a better way to go than this.

Comment: Yes, but still the user choice and depend on the problem. If he already have the variable in .mat file and map is too big to do, eval can be another easy solution.